# How to GET request data using proxy for API in NextJS

Tags: api, next.js, cors

Locally I am trying to GET request data from an external API in NextJS. I have been through documentation saying to use `next.config.js` rewrites, but all it returns is 404 from my request, but in the url (localhost:3000/property/listings) if I go to the path it gives me `{"success":false,"message":"Resource not found.","errors":[]}`.

The main reason I am trying this is because if I don't use a proxy I get CORS errors. When trying to request data from say `https://example.com` from `localhost:3000` I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/listings' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.

I've been advised to use a proxy, but the approach I have taken doesn't seem to be working for the GET request. Is using `next.config.js` rewrites the right thing to be using here?

Any help with this would really be appreciated!

**next.config.js**

```
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const rewritesConfig = isDevelopment
  ? [
      {
        source: "/property/:path*/",
        destination: `${process.env.PROPERTY_API_BASE_URL }/:path*/`,
      },
    ]
  : [];

module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
    rewrites: async () => rewritesConfig,
};
```

**GET request in page**

```
axios.get('/property/listings', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROPERTY_API_KEY
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log('SUCCESS', res);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to solve the issue with an API endpoint instead of proxy.

```
    const url = `${process.env.PROPERTY_API_BASE_URL}/listings`;
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROPERTY_API_KEY
        }
    };

    await axios.get(url, config).then(({ data }) => {
        res.status(200).json({ data })
    }).catch(({ err }) => {
        res.status(400).json({ err })
    })
}
```